# Not getting the AM/PM when switching to localize(languages)

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I am working on Localization for .net web application for the first time. When I am selecting the **English (en-US)** it's working fine. But when I'm selecting/switching to **French, Spanish and German** not getting **AM/PM**.

It's printing like **11:56:32**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
lblErrorMessage.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")

}

protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {

        if (Session["Lang"] != null)
            language = Session["Lang"].ToString();

        if ((language != null) && (language != ""))
        {
            if (language == "English")
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Trim());
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Trim());
            }
            else
            {
                switch (language)
                {
                    case "English":
                        language = "en-US";
                        break;
                    case "French":
                        language = "fr-FR";
                        break;
                    case "Spanish":
                        language = "es-ES";
                        break;
                    case "German":
                        language = "de-DE";
                        break;
                }

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
                //Resources.Resource.Login;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Trim());
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Trim());
        }
    }
```

**Can you please help on this to get AM/PM by using above Languages?**

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("de-DE")));` seems to reproduce this just by itself.

Comment: It looks like de-DE's `DateTimeFormat`'s `AMDesignator` and `PMDesignator` fields hold empty strings.

Comment: AM/PM is a cultural thing. Other languages won't necessarily show the time in that way.

Comment: This behaviour seems to be right. According to [this article](https://www.dummies.com/languages/german/basic-german-telling-time/): _"Unlike in the United States, Germans don’t use the a.m./p.m. system."_ It also says _"They use the 12-hour system in casual conversation and the 24-hour system when they want to avoid any chance of misunderstanding."_.

Comment: You'll also find some countries/languages/locales prefer the 24 hour clock, where AM/PM would be redundant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be correct when telling time in German.

Comment: @Llama, Then how they will enter the time in the application if they want like AM/PM?

Comment: Presumably in 24 hour time. For display you probably want [`DateTime.Now.ToString("T")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-long-time-t-format-specifier).

Comment: You can see how `T` reflects for different cultures [here](https://rextester.com/DOTI79133). This appears to be normal for these cultures.

Comment: _"Then how they will enter the time in the application if they want like AM/PM?"_ - they won't. That's extremely uncommon in Germany and only ever used if forced to by clocks/software that uses US time designation, only. It's commonly considered inferior to the the 24H system and looked upon with a frown. _Any_ German can and will use 24H happily; it's taught in 1st grade of school.

Comment: @Llama Understood, thank you.

Comment: ^^ Same probably applies for several other countries, especially across europe.